# Having trouble with value returning

Tags: swift3

During swift coding, I would like to get the value form my function, but something went wrong, it shows an error:

> Error: Use of unresolved Identifier 'amount'

What it the correct way to get "amount" from this function?

```
func UserAmountGET() -> Int{
    let url = NSURL(string: myIP + "users/amount")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else{
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        let amount = Int(json["data"][0]["username"].stringValue)!
    }

    task.resume()
    return amount  // Error: Use of unresolved Identifier 'amount'
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that the `amount` variable is in the scope of the network request's closure, and cannot be accessed from the main body of the function. Presumably, your network request could take some time to complete, so you could use a closure instead that runs when the network request returns.

```
func UserAmountGET(completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: myIP + "users/amount")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else{
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        let amount = Int(json["data"][0]["username"].stringValue)!

        completion(amount)

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Then you would call your method like this:

```
UserAmountGET(completion: { amount in

    // use the `amount` value here

})
```

This usage of closures is more natural with asynchronous callbacks like network requests.

Comment: If something could be improved about my answer, please let me know if you are going to downvote me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way, if I want to access 'amount' from main body function, what method should I use?

Comment: Inside the main body of the `UserAmountGET` function? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Never mind, I've got it wrong, there's a logical mistake in my thought. Anyways, thanks for the answer.